# To refresh another JSF page on submit from one page

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to add records to datatable by submitting a form built using JSF and primefaces which gets popped up from the page containing datatable.On submit of the form the data gets updated to database but i need to refresh/update the datatable with the submitted data.Is there any way using which i can refer the main page on submit from the form so that i can refresh/update the datatable.

JSF code snippet containing datatable

```
<h:form id="lpcForm">
  <!-- <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" /> -->
  <div id="content">         
  <h:commandLink ajax="true" id="cmdLinkAdd" value="Add" action="#{lpcBean.addRecord}"
     target="_blank" update="@form" process="@this" />


     <p:dataTable var="lpcData" id="lpcDataTable" widgetVar="lpcTable"
        value="#{lpcBean.lpcIdList}" selection="#{lpcBean.selectedRows}"
        editable="true" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="1110"
        scrollHeight="330" styleClass="datatable">

              <!--Contents of the table-->
      </p:dataTable>
  </div>
```

On clicking the command link i get the web page popup through which i can submit the data,the snippet of which is as below

```
<h:form id="addLpc">
        <p:focus context="addLpc" />
        <div align="center">


            <h:panelGrid id="addLpcForm" columns="3" >

                contents of the form
            </h:panelGrid>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" ajax="true"
                action="#{lpcRecordAddition.formSubmit}"  />
            <h:outputText />
        </div>


    </h:form>
```

on submit of this form i need the datatable in other page to get updated.

Comment: Add `update=":lpcForm:lpcData"` to your `p:commandButton`.

Comment: i get error "Cannot find component with identifier ":lpcForm:lpcData" referenced from "addLpc:submitButton" if i do this

Comment: Maybe it should be `update="lpcForm:lpcData"` just check the id the form is acquiring at client side.

Comment: I am getting same kind of error when i use update="lpcForm:lpcDataTable".lpcDataTable is the id of the datatable

Comment: I misread your code, it should be with the datatable id of course.

Comment: You have to precede `:` so that the absolute path is used. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @user1983983 i tried using both ways but getting same kind of error :(

Comment: Oh, you are open a new browser tab or window for adding a record?!

Comment: I am adding new window.

Comment: It is not possible to update the `datatTable` in another window. You have two options: you can use a `p:poll` in the first window to update the `dataTable` at a specified time intervall or you use a modal dialog, which you can achieve by using `p:dialog`. I would strongly recommend the second solution, which is additionally a better approach regarding UX.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following for the `commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" ajax="true"
   action="#{lpcRecordAddition.formSubmit}" update=":lpcForm:lpcDataTable" />
```

Comment: `ajax="true"` is not needed. It is the default value.